# ¿Cómo crear un Dialogo con un Cuadro de Texto Simple en Android?

Tags: java, android

Necesito llamar un cuadro de dialogo en Android con un `Edittext` con un texto inicialmente preestablecido, con botones `Accept`, `Cancel` y capturar el evento si se ha pulsado alguno de ellos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esto es lo que se me ocurre, aunque no es muy bueno :/

```
tuEdittext.setText("Texto por default");

tuEdittext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
             abrirDialogo();
             esconderTeclado();

        }
    }
});

public void abrirDialogo(){
     AlertDialog.Builder dialogo1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);  
            dialogo1.setTitle("Aviso");  
            dialogo1.setMessage("¿Quieres clickear un botón?");            
            dialogo1.setCancelable(false);  
            dialogo1.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogo1, int id) {  
                    aceptar();  
                }  
            });  
            dialogo1.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogo1, int id) {  
                    cancelar();
                }  
            });            
            dialogo1.show();        
        }
}



public void esconderTeclado(){
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN
);

}



    public void aceptar() {
        tuEdittext.setText("Aceptar");
    }

    public void cancelar() {
  tuEdittext.setText("Cancelar");
        finish();
    }
```

Comment: y no se puede mostrar el dialogo con el edittext adentro y capturar ese nuevo texto para enviarlo otra vez a la vista como para guardar en una BDD o algo asi?.. es decir personalizar mas el dialogo con imagenes, editetext y otros botones si se necesitara? creo que era con un inflater pero no se como exactamente

Comment: puedes crear otra pregunta nueva mas detallado para que todos puedan ayudarte :D